# Как реализовать напоминания о брошенной корзине?

Tags: javascript, html

Буду очень признателен за подсказанную идею или решение.

Есть сайт, у которого имеется корзина.

Возможно ли, а если возможно то как, реализовать такую функцию, чтобы зарегистрированным пользователям на email высылалось напоминание о добавленных и не купленных товарах в корзине?

Интересует именно возможность реализации на HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Html и JavaScript (в браузере) не умеют посылать письма. Да и вообще-то если пользователь ушёл с сайта, то нет больше вашего html и js

Comment: Напоминания вне сессии высылать в любом случае не получится. Нужен, например, сценарий на сервере, который будет запускаться по графику. Хотите js - копайте в сторону node.js...

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете поставить слушатель на событие типа [pagehide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event), и в случае если в корзине присутствуют товары отправлять об этом сигнал на Ваш backend, где Вы уже сможете реализовать логику уведомлений, например, по прошествии определенного времени.

*Мой ответ предполагает что у Вас уже имеется emeil пользователя, а он сам залогинен.*